# Problems with sending array through ajax

Tags: javascript

Hello stackoverflow community, I need help with my JavaScript. How can I transfer array with id of `kasce`?

When I'm printing array in `ajax_import.php` file, it prints nothing. So probably my array is empty.

Here is my code:

```
function SubmitImp() {
    var import_tasken = document.getElementById("import_tasken");
    //import_tasken.style.display = "none";
    var kasce = document.getElementsByName("impTaskCh");
    var array = "";
    for (i = 0; i < kasce.length; i++) {
        array[i] = kasce[i].getAttribute('id');
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'modules/projects/ajax/ajax_import.php',
        data: {
            data: array,
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("Viskas ok!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you don't have an array, `array` is clearly defined as a string, try creating an array instead

Comment: How? I've never done this before in JavaScript so I don't know HOW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems there.

First, you're not sending an array, you're sending a blank string.. Here, you put a string in `array`:

```
var array = "";
```

Later, you do this:

```
array[i] = kasce[i].getAttribute('id');
```

...which is trying to assign a new value to a single character of the string. You can't do that, strings are immutable in JavaScript; the line ends up not changing the string at all.

`array[i]` is a single character in the string. You're trying to assign a string to it.

To make `array` an array, use:

```
var array = [];
```

Next, and this may not be a problem, here:

```
data: {
    data: array,
}
```

...you're telling jQuery to send a URI-encoded parameter called `data` with the value `array`. jQuery will call `toString` on `array`, which with a true array ends up being `Array#join`. That may well be what you want, you'll get something like this:

```
firstId,secondId,thirdId
```

Your PHP should look for it as `$_POST['data']`.

---

Side note: You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you never declare your `i` variable. You want to declare it.

Comment: Can you help me with one more stuff. Ive got this loop  `for (i = 0; i < kasce.length; i++) {
  var checkIF = document.getElementById(i);` Am i writing this corectly  document.getElementById(i)? Because im getting error :/

Comment: @McLaren: That would be correct if you had elements with `id="0"`, `id="1"`, etc., in your document. I assume you don't. :-) The code in your question accessing `kasce` is correct, assuming you have multiple elements with `name="impTaskCh"`. (Except you need to declare `i`, see the [new] end of the answer above.)